# How to access lower/upper bound for an interval - R language?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

Suppose that in R we have this list of intervals :

```
    i <- Intervals(
  matrix(
    c(0,5000,  
      0,5000,
      7000,10000,  
      7000,10000,
      7000,10000,
      10000,15000,  
      10000,15000
    ),
    byrow = TRUE,
    ncol = 2
  ),
  closed = c( TRUE, TRUE ),
  type = "R"
)
```

- The first interval is closed : [0,5000].
- The third interval is : [7000,10000].

***Questions :***

1. How can i access the lower/upper bounds of this interval ( the
   values 0 & 5000).
2. How can i create an empty n-interval variable
       with a lenght of n intervals.

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the information that `Intervals` is an S4 class in the `intervals` package. I'm not familiar with the package, but the following seem to work:

```
min(i)
max(i)
n <- 7
e <- matrix(as.integer(rep(NA, n*2)), nrow=n)
j <- Intervals(e)
```

You should definitely test them to ensure they are performing as you expect.